# How to perform reverse of relative path in DOS?

Tags: batch-file, dos

I want to delete some files from a folder, so I do this:

```
DEL "C:\Documents and Settings\name\My Documents\application\v10-105 CODE\v10-105 CODE\app\bin\Release\ExSimSeqNum-*.txt"
```

However, the folder "v10-105 CODE" changes very often (as version gets incremented).

In `../application/`, there is only one folder and in that single folder, there are two folders.
Is there a way to generalize going down this path? I tried this:

```
DEL "C:\Documents and Settings\name\My Documents\application\v*\v*\app\bin\Release\ExSimSeqNum-*.txt"
```

but I get "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
C:
CD "C:\Documents and Settings\name\My Documents\application"
CD v*\v*
DEL app\bin\Release\ExSimSeqNum-*.txt
```

The reason is do not use * inside quote to match multiple characters, it won't work

Comment: I don't see how quotes have any bearing on use of wildcard character when using CD. The CD command with two wildcards works fine on Vista both with and without quotes. I presume it is the same in XP and beyond, but I haven't tested.

Comment: @dbenham If wildcards in quotes aren't causing the issue, what is? I am curious to know the reasoning behind this strange syntax.

Comment: @BaliC - The fact that CD works with wildcard at multiple levels is a surprise to me as well. I'm just saying the quotes make no difference. Based on experiment, CD looks at the 1st directory entry (sorted alphabetically) that matches the wildcard, and if it is a folder, it moves on to the next level. If it first finds a file instead of a folder then it fails. For example, the answer will fail if the "application" folder contains a file named v1.txt because the wildcard finds file "v1.txt" prior to finding folder "v10-105 CODE".